# How can I call a library function with machine code?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, x86

Sorry if the question is worded badly but I have disassembled a compiled file which includes a few standard libraries using objdump and saw the following instruction:

```
e8 d7 7d 00 00          call   8051bd0 <_IO_fgets>
```

Using GDB i confirmed that fgets is indeed located at 0x8051bd0 (and stays there upon reruns). The compilation is done using the following flags:

```
gcc -m32 -static -o test -O0 -ggdb test.c -fno-stack-protector -Wno-format-security
```

From my understanding the address 0x7ddc is retrieved during compile time from the linkage table and is not available during runtime. Now I am wondering if there exists an instruction which I can use (provided I can inject it during runtime and know a function address like 0x8051bd0) to achieve the same functionality? I tried looking at the different call instructions but I have no idea what to do with that information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `0x7dd7` is the relative offset, relative to the end of that call instruction.  That machine code is what actually runs on the hardware.  And yes, `-static` will make a non-PIE executable where absolute addresses are link-time constants.  It's certainly possible to inject a `call rel32` with the right offset, if you know the absolute address where the instruction will end up.  Of course at this point it's not "assembly" language anymore, but machine code.  You don't have an assembler + linker handling symbols -> offsets for you.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, I understand the offset version now. Also does that mean if I call r/m32 with 0x8051d0 it will achieve the same result, if the address stays the same?

Comment: Yes, if you move an address into a register first.  That's the standard way to call an absolute address.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot